# URLSearchParams to a file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using jstree and I want to click on a file in the tree and display the pdf file. here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#tree').jstree({
        'core' : {
           'data' : {
                'url' : function (node) {
                      return node.id === '#' ? 'assets/ajax_roots.json' : 'assets/ajax_children.json';
                    },
                'data' : function (node) {
              return { 'id' : node.id };
            }
        }
    },




$('#tree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
 // this gives the path
  var path = data.instance.get_path(data.node,'/'); 
   const url = new URL(window.location.href);

})
```

To make it clear, I want to add the path to my url. I am trying to do this with javascript using URLSearchParams I have this so far:

```
http://somewhere.com/index.html
```

However, I would like to have this:

```
http://somewhere.com/index.html/?file=/to/some/dir/filename.pdf
```

Could someone help me get stated
Thank you

Comment: What your expected output and Where is your `code` and a minimum effort to achieve this ?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Comment: This line " const url = new URL(window.location.href);" is what I have tried so far it returns http://somewhere.com/index.html. The first '/' may not be necessary. Lets say I am in a directory called web, the files are stored in a directory web/pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
var param = 'file=/to/some/dir/filename.pdf';
var _url = 'http://somewhere.com/index.html';
console.log("Before : ", _url);
    _url += (_url.split('?')[1] ? '&':'?') + param;
    console.log("After : ", _url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example

```js
const url = new URL('http://somewhere.com/index.html/')

url.searchParams.append('file', '/to/some/dir/filename.pdf')

console.log(url.toString()) // encode output
console.log(url.toString().replaceAll('%2F', '/')) // decode output

const expectedOutput = 'http://somewhere.com/index.html/?file=/to/some/dir/filename.pdf'
const currentOutput = url.toString().replaceAll('%2F', '/')

console.log(expectedOutput === currentOutput)
```

Comment: where are the `/` OP wanted ? You answer will open a file. OP wants to somehow want this `?file=/to/some/dir/filename.pdf`. You solution will not work.

Comment: `/` are encoded try `console.log(url.toString().replaceAll('%2F', '/'))` the output is the way `url.toString()` works. URL Encoded Characters in this link https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: At your insistence I have gone to check if I have read the question properly, I think I did so.